# "resolution" media query to refer to the actual screen

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to use the "resolution" media query to determine the actual DPI of the screen.

The code I am doing looks like this:

```
window.matchMedia(`(resolution: ${value}dpi)`).matches
```

But I find that the `value` for which this query is true is 96 on two different devices which do *not* have the same DPI.  On one machine, for instance, the actual DPI is 157.  `window.devicePixelRatio` is equal to 1 on both of these machines.  On a third device, the actual DPI is 215, yet the above query tells me it is 192 (exactly double 96), and `window.devicePixelRatio` is 2.

I have seen CSS media queries that look like "@media" or "@media screen", but if I put either of those in the string I pass to `matchMedia` it never comes up true no matter what the value is.  Yet I feel like I *must* be missing something, because the spec says `resolution` is to match the actual resolution of the screen, and I'm never seeing that happen.

Comment: Basically when it comes to screen resolution, browsers lie.

Comment: @Pointy so i fear... in 2019... still wrecking my API

Comment: The idea behind it all is that you're supposed to trust the device to tell you numbers that are "right" given what the physical reality is. Unfortunately that trust is abused sometimes (iPad mini).

Comment: @Pointy I'm not sure what you are saying.  Do some browsers not lie?  I don't have an iPad to test this on...

Comment: Well the iPad Mini is a particular example. It reports exactly the same geometry as the iPad (full size), but of course the screen is smaller. It affects everything: nominal 16px type on the Mini is considerably smaller than 16px type on the normal iPad. I'm sure there are lots of other examples in the wild world of Android devices too.

Comment: (Note that I'm definitely not an iPad expert; that's the way it was a couple years ago.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS `<resolution>` units are based on CSS units, not on actual physical sizes.

So if we forget about the fact DPI is a printing unit and thus when it relates to a screen it should be called PPI, `<resolution>` won't show it to you.

Instead this unit is really how many `pixels per CSS inch` (where `pixel` is the smallest physical dot of your display), and a `CSS inch` is defined as `96px` (where `px` is the magic CSS unit, not any physical thing).

So what you have here is merely just `devicePixelRatio * 96`, and doesn't give you any information about the physical density of your screen (which would require your browser to know the actual physical size of your display, which is impossible, for the simple fact you can use a Beam Projector as display).

Comment: argh.  i was reading somewhere that a CSS media query could be used to work around the inability to determine real screen resolution in javascript.  I *really* *really* need this and have been blocked for many months on the inability to do this.

Comment: The only way to get this is to ask your user to tell you their actual display dimensions.

Comment: yeah this was the original workaround during development, but actually requiring this - for any... every... user visiting your web site to somehow interact with it in order for the site to display correctly - seems wholely unacceptable.

Comment: How exactly does one go about fixing this situation?  Honestly, I'm at my wits end.

Comment: Yes I know ;-) Why do you absolutely need this though? While I said CSS `px` is *not a physical thing*, it's not entirely true. UAs should determine the distance of viewing in order to set this magic unit. So a mobile phone won't have the same value as a desktop monitor. That's usually enough to provide a similar experience across different devices.

Comment: Well, my API presents a way to drawing based on physical sizes and it guarantees they will be that size on any platform. So for instance, if you tell it to draw a button one inch tall and two inches wide, because that is what you have determined is needed for your large fingered users, that's what it does.

Comment: Then I'm sorry, but there is no way to do it for every users. The only thing I can think of would be a dictionary of known devices, with their actual dimensions, and a way to finger-print them all. Don't know if such a list already exists though, but that would be the only viable way for your API to exist. (and once again, it will inevitably fail with beam projectors, but I guess it's less of a concern).

Comment: Is it even possible to determine what device the user's screen is?  (Oh, and the prompting the user thing also fails on multi-monitor setups)

Comment: I honestly hope it is not possible, but I also know a lot of info are leaked by browsers. For instance Safari does use the device Color Profile to set its canvas colors, so there, you could grab what color profile was used, with a bit of fluck, that could be a vendor unique profile, and then with the px size you may be able to retrieve what monitor it is. But obviously that's not a simple task, and once again I hope very much it's not possible.